# Google Calendar CRUD programming

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Is that possible to CRUD events in google calendar programming from my android app

I need to add events in android native calendar by using code 
Then in need to read it and
 I need to update or delete that event 

Note only the events added from my app

Comment: You can use Google Calender API/SDk. Follow the steps mentioned in the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to apply CRUD operations to your Google Calendar from the Android platform. In order to do so, I recommend you take a look at the Android's [Calendar provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

The calendar provider not only will allow you to work with Google calendar but also other types of calendars that the user may have configured, such as Exchange.

For more examples on how to use this tool, you can also check [this blog post](https://www.zoftino.com/how-to-read-and-write-calendar-data-in-android).